# linux print variable vaule in foreach loop a1,a2,a3

Tags: linux, perl, csh

I have a an old csh script (which hopefully I have time to rewrite in perl) which has a series of variables wmr1, wmr2 ... wmr24. What I would like to do is echo the values of each variable using a foreach loop eg

```
foreach i(`seq 1 24`)
   echo ${wmr$i}
end
```

Can this be done in csh or using a perl one liner (using a symbolic refernce?)? I am not sure how to combine the integer `$i` with `wmr` and output the value of `$wmr1` `$wmr2` etc. `echo ${wmr$i}` in the loop gives me the error `Missing }.`

Comment: Surely, it can be done.  Show us what did you try?  Is this a coding service?

Comment: @devnull I have tried echo ${wmr$i} and various other combinations. There isn't much out there in terms of csh help and I wasn't sure how best to scour the web for help in this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
 foreach i (`seq 1 24`)
     eval 'echo $wm'$i
 end
```

The eval statement will evaluate the string given to it. 
So replace echo with any other command you may want to use.